# market link with GA Android Campaign Tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using this URL builder to configure GA Android campaign tracking:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-builder

The URL that it generates uses standard scheme:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysite.myapp...

Using this  style URL gives customers the choice of opening in their browser vs. play store, where as market://details?id=com.mysite.myapp...does not (our preferred UX).

Question: Can anyone confirm that this market:// URL will work with GA campaign tracking as well? I'm testing this, but the tracking is unreliable for me and I don't have confidence in the results I'm seeing. I hope Google is going to improve this feature.

market://details?id=com.mysite.myapp...

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `market://` scheme will work with Google Analytics campaign tracking. You can use the [GA URL builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns) and just replace the scheme with `market://`.

The `&referrer` param on that link, if you include one, will be passed to your application on install as a string extra with the `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent, regardless of whether you use `https://` or `market://` scheme.

GA will use that referrer string for campaign tracking.

Understood that you prefer to use `market://`, but wanted to put out to others who may read this that the `market://` scheme is officially deprecated, in favor of `https://`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please link to your source?